# myBatis: как при сохранении сущности вернуть её?

Tags: java, mybatis

У меня есть сущность, довольно простая:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Есть мапер, который сохраняет эту сущность в базу и возвращает созданный ID.

```
@Insert("insert into users(username, password) values(#{user.username}, #{user.password})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
Long save(@Param("user") User user);
```

Потом сервис получает сущность по этому ID:

```
@Override
public User save(User user) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(
            mapper.findById(
                    Optional.ofNullable(mapper.save(user))
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotSavedException("Не удалось сохранить: " + user)))
    )
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotSavedException("Не удалось сохранить: " + user));
}
```

Таким образом, для возврата сущности при её сохранении, как это делается в приличных домах, мы имеем два запроса в базу - на сохранение сущности и на её получение по полученному при сохранении id. Дороговато.

Существует ли способ сразу вернуть сущность при сохранении и обойтись, таким образом, одним запросом?

Comment: Что мешает просто сохранить в `user` возвращённый `id` и вернуть этот же `user`, не делая дополнительный запрос?

Comment: Решение выглядит костыльным, поскольку мы возвращаем не сохранённую сущность, а то, что получили. Я понимаю, что это и сохранится, но это уже поддавки какие-то. Кстати, возвращает не id, а количество сохранённых строк.

Comment: Единственное отличие объекта `user` до и после вызова `save` - это наличие значения у поля `id`. А `@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")` как раз для того, чтобы в возвращаемом значении был идентификатор сохранённой сущности.

Comment: 1. Фактически, `@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")` возвращает не ID, а число сохранённых строк (во всяком случае, у меня). Я писал об этом выше. 2. Это если всё ок, отличием является наличие id. Если же разработчик допустил какую-то ошибку, когда описывал сохранение сущности, которая будет приводить к некорректному сохранению полей, ему будет очень непросто это выяснить.

Comment: 1. Перечитайте [документацию](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#insert.2C_update_and_delete) 2. Другого способа нет. Плюс и одновременно минус MyBatis в аскетичности возможностей и необходимости программисту работать с низкоуровневыми деталями

Comment: 1. Документация вещь полезная, когда она соответствует тому, что на практике https://pastebin.com/LE66u7F8 https://pasteboard.co/IMTtyEH.png

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно используете `useGeneratedKeys`.

#### @Options(userGeneratedKeys=true,...)

Эта опция использует [возможность](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-int-) JDBC вернуть значения после выполнения `insert` (если БД поддерживает).

Важный момент, что возвращаются сгенерированные значения (а их может быть несколько!) в свойства параметра (а не так результат из метода мапера):

> Identifies a property into which MyBatis will set the key value returned by getGeneratedKeys, or by a selectKey child element of the insert statement. Default: unset. Can be a comma separated list of property names if multiple generated columns are expected.

Т.е. нужно правильно задать куда mybatis должен проставить значение и из какой колонки:

```
@Insert("insert into users(username, password) values(#{user.username}, #{user.password})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty="user.id" keyColumn="ID")
Long save(@Param("user") User user);
```

После выполнения метода, mybatis присвоит значение колонки `id` свойству `id` у параметра `user`.

Возвращаемый же результат из метода мапера, который делает insert/update/delete, это всегда количество затронутых записей (т.е. для вставки это количество вставленных, в данном случае у вас всегда возвращается 1, что и видно на скриншоте из коментария).

Правильная реализация метода в сервисе будет такая:

```
@Override
public User save(User user) {
    long numberOfInsertedRecords = mapper.save(user);
    if (numberOfInsertedRecords != 0) {
      ... 
    }
    return mapper.findById(user.getId());
}
```

#### @SelectKey

Если БД/драйвер не поддерживают userGeneratedKeys, то вместо `@Options` c `useGeneratedKeys` можно воспользоваться аннотацией `@SelectKey`, которая делает отдельный запрос, чтобы получить значение:

```
@Insert("insert into users(id, username, password) values(#{id}, #{user.username}, #{user.password})")
@SelectKey(statement = "SELECT nextval('user_id_seq')", keyProperty = "user.id", before = true, resultType = Long.class)
Long save(@Param("user") User user);
```

Обратите внимание, что тут запрос делается до вставки. И mybatis присваивает значение полю `id` до вставки и собственно запрос на вставку уже использует сгенерированное значение.

В этом случае реализация сервиса остается такая же как и для `@Options`.

Используя `@Insert` (т.е. [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) под капотом) в mybatis не возможно обойтись одним запросом. На сегодняшний момент не реализован мапинг возвращаемых значений в объект, как это сделано для обычного `@Select`, в частности тут не получится использовать `resultSet` и т.д. Т.е. если хотим вернуть всю запись нужно делать отдельный запрос.

#### Insert + Select одним запросом в postgresql

В некоторых СУБД можно сделать такой запрос, который одновременно и модифицирует и делает выборку. Например, в postgres:

```
insert into users(username, password) values(#{user.username}, #{user.password})
returning *
```

Такой запрос по сути аналогичен двум запросам:

```
insert into users(username, password) values(#{user.username}, #{user.password});
select * from user;
```

И его нужно выполнять как обычный select:

```
@Select("insert into users(username, password) values(#{user.username}, #{user.password})
returning *")
@Options(flushCache=true)
User save(@Param("user") User user);
```

Обратите внимание, что нужна опция `flushCache=true`, т.к. mybatis не знает, что реально выполняется модификация и нужно очистить кеш.